# Displaying Filepaths Correctly in Flask/Jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a setup in a flask app where I can use a form to upload a file into the `static/img` directory for my application, and the metadata is stored in a record in a database.

When someone makes a request to the appropriate page, I want to read the file from the server using the filepath saved in the database.

Here's an example of the record when it's pulled from the database:

```
(3, 'My Info', 'My Description', 'www.url.com', 'static\\img\\aws_nameservers.PNG')
```

What I'd like to do is combine the last item in the above record with the `url_for` function to render the image stored at that location.

What I have right now is a `set` method that gets the last part of the file path:

```
{% set filepath = workshop_info[4][7:] %}
```

This returns `img\\aws_nameservers.PNG`

Then inside an `img` tag I have the following:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=filepath) }}">
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
<img src="/static/img%5Caws_nameservers.PNG">
```

It seems like a simple thing, but I can't figure out how to render the string correctly inside the jinja2 template.

Thank you.

If there is a better approach than what I'm attempting, I'm happy to get corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the forward slash (`/`) instead of backslash (`\`) at the file path. You can replace them either in the Python code or in the template using a filter, e.g.:

```
{% set filepath = "img\\aws_nameservers.PNG" | replace("\\", "/") %}
{{ url_for('static', filename=filepath) }}

# Outputs: /static/img/aws_nameservers.PNG
```

You can also use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath) module to convert between the Windows and Unix style paths.